# "Run-time error '1004': We couldn't paste this data because it took too long. Try reducing the size of the selection."

Tags: excel, vba, remote-desktop

This error is happening when the application is trying to a paste formula into an entire column. The code which is trying to paste the formula has been working for a few months and it seems to be consistently throwing the error on a particular remote computer.

I copied the file on my device and tried running it locally. It throwed this error only the first two times, but after that, it seems to be working fine.

I tried searching everywhere but I could not find this exact error elsewhere. All the other questions I found were related to using Select which I do not use. The exact error message I am getting reads:

> "Run-time error '1004':  We couldn't paste this data because it took
> too long. Try reducing the size of the selection.  If you're copying
> from a remote computer, your network performance may be the cause."

[Here's a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ciig.png)

Below is the function where the error is happening and the line causing the error is indicated:

```
Public Function AutofillFormula()

'declaring variables
Dim shParts As Worksheet
Dim ShapesRange As range
Dim last_Row As Long

'assigning sheet to sheet variable
Set shParts = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Parts")
Set tableParts = getTableFromSheet(worksheets("Parts"))
colShapes = Find_Column("Shapes", "Parts", 1) ' This is a custom function which returns the letter of the column in a sheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Apply the formula to the row number 2 of the Shapes column in Parts sheet
shParts.range(colShapes & "2").Formula = "=INDEX(Sheet2!AA:AA,MATCH([@[Part Alpha]],Sheet2!A:A,0))"

'identify last filled cell of column A in Parts sheet
last_Row = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Parts").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'create dynamic range
Set ShapesRange = shParts.range(colShapes  & "2:" & colShapes & last_Row)

'Copy the formula
shParts.range(colShapes & "2").Copy

'Paste the copied formula to the dynamic range
ShapesRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone ' **Line causing the error**

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

The number of rows where the formula is getting pasted is 15920. I ran this file with triple the number of rows on different devices and I am not getting this error.

From the error message, it could be related to the network performance on this particular remote computer, but I don't see why I would get it on my local computer a couple of times. Any help with the cause of this error and potential fixes is much appreciated.

Comment: Can't you assign the `Formula` property directly? `ShapeRange.Formula = shParts.Range(colShapes & "2").Formula`

Comment: Even better: `ShapeRange.Formula = "=INDEX(Sheet2!AA:AA,MATCH([@[Part Alpha]],Sheet2!A:A,0))"`. Insert the original formula to the entire range in one go.

Comment: While you're at it, make it a string constant so easier to maintain next time.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks! Applying the formula directly works.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue now whilst trying to paste any amount of data in Excel on a remote computer, I noticed a "Display Settings" message on the status bar, clicked it and chose the compatibility option, I was then able to paste data.
I can't explain this and I doubt MS can either...